# Issues with setting non-allowable stuff in while loop

Tags: javascript

Trying to get only odd numbers, or keep looping

Tried to set var as constraint and do if else, this way seems the most intuitive

```
do {
  v = +prompt("enter an odd number");

} while (isNaN(v) || v < 0 || v % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `v > 0` instead of `v < 0`?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What's the actual question? There's a big difference between `&&` and `||`.

Comment: If `isNaN(v)` is `true`, I don't think either of the other conditions *can* be.

Comment: yeah sorry, I see what now it should be || OR instead of && , also I had another suggestion to do v>0 , but this is confusing, why would I want it to repeat if v is greater than 0, only for when v LESS THAN that I want it to repeat..

Comment: You need to decide which "direction" your check will go and create consistent conditions. Trivial debugging in the REPL will help you solve the logic issue.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions were not correct. It should have been an **OR** condition and the check should be *checking if it's an even number* and continue if its not.
    '

```js
do {
  v = +prompt("enter an odd number");

} while (isNaN(v) || v < 0 || v % 2 == 0);
```